# Extract values from file efficiently

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, sh

Let's say I have this file: `version.h`

```c
#define MAJ_VERSION         1
#define MIN_VERSION         4
#define BLD_VERSION         0
```

Using a bash script, how do I extract the values in 3 separate variables such as `$maj==1`, `$min==4` and `$bld==0`?

I've tried several approach around this regex: `s/\_VERSION\s*(\d*)/` which allows me to extract on each line the value in the first match group  but I've failed to find an elegant solution.

For instance, this doesn't work (and also needs a counter to disambiguate the 3 values):

```sh
str=$(cat version.h)
for var in ${str[@]}; do
    echo
    if [[ ${var} =~ (\_VERSION\s*)([0-9]*) ]]; then
        echo "match: '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}'"
        echo "match: '${BASH_REMATCH[2]}'"
    fi
done
```

Comment: To match digits, use `[0-9]`, not `\d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use bash and GNU sed:

```
source <(sed -E 's/.*(MAJ|MIN|BLD)_VERSION[[:blank:]]+(.*)/\L\1="\2"/' version.h)
```

Verify the variable contents:

```
$ declare -p maj min bld
declare -- maj="1"
declare -- min="4"
declare -- bld="0"
```

Comment: Nice one-liner! How are `maj`, `min`, `bld` variables captured? Also, I have a small issue with this, in some context, version.h is generated on windows and has CRLF line endings, I end up with `typeset min=$'4\C-M'`. This causes issue when performing arithmetic operation such as `$(($maj+1))`. How would you deal with that?

Comment: For the latter I would change `(.*) ` to `([^\r]*)`

Comment: For the former, consider what I am capturing on the left hand side, and what I replace on the rough side. Then investigate bash "process substitution" and the builtin `source` command.

Comment: GNU sed `\L` does lower casing

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I tried changing `(.*)` to `([^\r]*)` first, but it doesn't seem to work... No difference when excluding both  `\r` and `\n`

Comment: You could try `sed -E -e 's/\r$//' -e 'my original answer'` to "pre-remove" the carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
 maj=$(grep MAJ_VERSION version.h | awk '{print $3}')
 min=$(grep MIN_VERSION version.h | awk '{print $3}')
 bld=$(grep BLD_VERSION version.h | awk '{print $3}')
```

Comment: @Fluffy well that's one of the most simple forms of awk. It simply prints out the 3rd column of its input

Comment: 6 processes and 3 pipes isn't exactly doing it "efficiently"! You never need grep when you're using awk, and one awk command could produce all of the values at one time which you could then simply read in the calling shell or save as array values

Comment: @Ed Morton I just provided a very simple & working solution. I never claimed it was the most efficient. I fully agree it could be better

Comment: I mentioned efficiency not because of anything you claimed but because the OPs question is how to `Extract values from file efficiently`.

Comment: Ok sure, however I would very much like to see how many variations of the source file could break my solution, and how many could break yours "more efficient" solution. For example for me something that relies on a specific order of input lines to work, I wouldn't really call it "efficient", just because it's using a more sophisticated awk..

Answer (score 0):

If the values always exist in that order in the input file:

```
$ read -r maj min bld < <(awk '{printf "%s ", $3} END{print ""}' file)
$ echo "$maj, $min, $bld"
1, 4, 0
```

If there's more than the 3 lines you show us in the input file then tweak the awk to:

```
awk '/^#define.*VERSION/{printf "%s ", $3} END{print ""}' file
```

If the order isn't predefined then tweak it again to:

```
awk '/^#define.*VERSION/{sub(/_.*/,"",$2); f[$2]=$3} END{print f["MAJ"], f["MIN"], f["BLD"]}' file
```

If there's any other issues, do tell...

Comment: Thanks for your thorough input, I have one last problem with this (repeating the above comment): in some context, version.h is generated on windows and has CRLF line endings, I end up with `typeset min=$'4\C-M'`. This causes issue when performing arithmetic operation such as `$(($maj+1))`. How would you deal with that?

Comment: throw in a `sub(/\r/,"")` before the references to `$3`, e.g. `{sub(/\r/,""); printf "%s ", $3}`.